# Genotype -/- vs delta/delta

Tags: genetics

In https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neuron.2018.07.033, Pan et al. use the designation TMC1^delta/delta to describe a mouse strain lacking a functional TMC1 gene.  What if any is the different between the delta/delta superscript and a -/- superscript in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The delta refers to a *mutant allele*, in this case a cysteine point mutant. The -/- refers to a homozygous *null allele*, in this case a knockout.